# OpenVPN does not appear to clear the route table when a VPN tunnel is broken

Tags: openvpn, route

I have set up a Raspberry Pi (called `blitzen`, installed with Jessie) on my local network to act as a VPN gateway for all computers on the local network to use to access the internet.

I am using `iptables` to NAT the OpenVPN connection (`tun0`) and forward packets from `eth0` to it. I am using `dnsmasq` and DHCP to configure all computers on the network to use this server as the default route to the internet.

This works well.

However, if the ADSL model crashes, I have a problem. OpenVPN notices that the `tun0` is defective and disconnects. It then attempts to reconnect but fails because it cannot resolve the host name of the VPN server:

```
Nov  3 17:27:20 blitzen ovpn-TunnelBearGermany[3020]: RESOLVE: Cannot resolve host address: de.tunnelbear-ios.com: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

Investigating, it appears that, when the tunnel is torn down, the old route table is left active:

```
$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         172.18.13.37    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 tun0
46.101.162.205  192.168.2.1     255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 eth0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     202    0        0 eth0
172.18.13.1     172.18.13.37    255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 tun0
172.18.13.37    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun0
192.168.2.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

If I manually remove the default route and reconfigure it to point to the ADSL modem, then the Pi happily resolves the VPN server name, and immediately reconnects. Everything returns to the happy state.

My question is - assuming that this behaviour is normal - How can I automate reverting the route table when the tunnel collapses? Is there an appropriate hook (in OpenVPN, or perhaps in the generic network package) to do this?